# JPA Query with Instant = 0

Tags: java, spring, jpa

There is a `Person` entity with `deleteTime` `Instant` field.

```
import java.time.Instant;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
class Person {
    // other fields
    Instant deleteTime;
}
```

I want to search for all entities where the `deleteTime = 0`. I would like to avoid a method with `Instant` as parameter. This can be achieved with a `@Query` i.e.

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Person e WHERE e.deleteTime = 0L")
List<Person> findAllActive();
```

The problem is that my IDE says about type mismatch. Is there a way to pass `Instant.EPOCH` instead of `0L` to the custom Query?

Comment: The fact that your IDE is complaining doesn't mean it might not work. Have you tried it? That being said something like this should work AFAIK `e.deleteTime = java.time.Instant.EPOCH`.

Comment: It does work, but it's okay to leave the warning?

Comment: The IDE sometimes has tricky warnings, it it static code analysis so it might not always be accurat. But as mentioned (I edited my initial comment) something like this `e.deleteTime = java.time.Instant.EPOCH` should work as well.

Comment: It works, no warnings, thanks @M.Deinum!